# How can i sort integers in a list, if they are in a string?

Tags: python, sorting, nested-lists

I have a controlled assessment, and need to be able to order scores from a test in numerical and alphabetical order. How do i do this if they are connected to the persons name who completed the quiz. All names are within 1 list, For example ["John, 9"], ["alfie, 6"] etc

any help much appreciated!

Comment: What language are you writing it in? A general apporach would be to split the input string by `,` into two parts, then turn the second string into integer, add it into a structure with the first one, write a comparator and finally sort.

Comment: Split the string, extract the integers and order the main list based on that.

Comment: I am writing in python, and am a total beginner to programming, thanks for your help.

Comment: You should edit your question and add the Python tag, this will attract more programmers

Comment: Look at [`str.split()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) and [`int()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int). :)

Comment: Oh, and at [`sorted(key=…)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted).

Comment: I have lists within a list eg: class1 = [["dave" 6], ["fred" 8], ["george" 10]], and when i attempt to split them, i get an error saying: "TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple" But i can't find the reason why? thanks again for everyone's help!

Comment: I just posted my answer when I saw your new comment… I hope you can figure out the solution with it anyhow?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to sort a list of strings based on a transformation on each of these strings, you can use the function `sorted` with the `key` keyword argument:

```
>>> l = ['10', '9', '100', '8']
>>> sorted(l)
['10', '100', '8', '9']
>>> sorted(l, key=int)
['8', '9', '10', '100']
>>> def transformation(x):
...     return -int(x)
...
>>> sorted(l, key=transformation)
['100', '10', '9', '8']
```

What the `key` function does is that the strings are not compared directly, but the values that are returned by the function are.

Comment: This looks perfect. thankyou so much! i am really struggling with this assessment so any help i can get is a huge bonus!